# Can one table span multiple classes?

Tags: foreign-keys, ormlite

One of my OrmLite classes/tables is getting far too big for its own good and needs to be refactored.  I'd like to split the class apart without splitting up the table.

Before refactoring:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Table") public class Employee {
   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true) final private int id;
   @DatabaseField final private String name;
   @DatanaseField final private String address;
}
```

After refactoring:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Table") public class Employee {
   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true) final private int id;
   @DatabaseField final private String name;
   @DatabaseField(foreign = true) final private Address;
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Table") public class Address {
   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true) final private int id;
   @DatabaseField final private String address;
}
```

Would this work or do I have to split the table to use foreign fields?

Comment: You talking about moving some of the fields to a new table and setting up a foreign object Jeff?

Comment: Sorry @Gray no, I mean I want to maintain the same table, but have it span across more than one class (using `tableName = "SameTableName"`).  There's no particular reason to divide the table itself, only the class.  And the SQL code for dividing existing database tables is pretty painful.  I suspect this is impossible in the current OrmLite implementation?

Comment: If I understand you, there is nothing wrong with copying the class to another class, removing some fields from the old class and some from the new class.  Then setting the same tableName on both.  I'm not sure exactly how it would work from a data perspective tho.  Can you edit your post and provide a quick example.